# If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $[[A, B], B] = 1$, then $[A, B]$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I am stuck on the following question:

If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $[[A, B], B] = 1$, then $[A, B]$ is abelian, where $[X, Y]$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $X$ and $Y$ as usual.

I have seen that $[A, B]$ is in the intersection of all the centralizer of each $b\in B$. And I am trying to show that $B$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then it follows that $[A, B] \subseteq Z(B)$, where $Z(B)$ denotes for the centre of $B$. Then the result follows.

But I have no idea how to show that $B$ is normal in $G$ or maybe I am completely on the wrong way.

Anyone can help?

Comment: There is a general result that $[X,Y]$ is normalized by $X$ and by $Y$. So $A$ normalizes $[A,B]$ and hence $A$ normalizes $C_G([A,B])$. Is that any help?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, but I still cannot solve my question.

Comment: I don't know why should $B$ be normal in $G$. The statement $[[A,B],B]=0$ "occurs" in the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$, and does not involve other elements. Maybe $B$ is normal in this subgrooup but for sure it will not be normal in the whole $G$. For instance, if $A= id$, then $[[A,B],B]=id$ is automatically satisfied but of course you cannot get that $B$ is normal from there.

Comment: I don't believe that it is true that $B$ is necessarily normal in $G$. I have indicated how to prove the result in my earlier comment. Since $B \le C_G([]A,B])$, we also have $B^A \le C_G([A,B])$, from which it follows that $[A,B] \le C_G([A,B])$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lemma** Let $A,B$ be subgroups a of group $G$, then both $A$ and $B$ normalize $[A,B]$.
**Proof** By symmetry we only prove this for $A$: let $a,a_1 \in A, b_1 \in B$, then
$$a^{-1}[a_1,b_1]a=(a_1a)^{-1}b_1^{-1}(a_1a)b_1.b_1^{-1}a^{-1}a_1^{-1}a_1b_1a=[a_1a,b_1][b_1,a] \in [A,B].$$

**Proposition** Let $A,B$ subgroups of a group $G$ and let $A$ or $B$ centralize $[A,B]$, then $[A,B]$ is abelian.
**Proof** Again, by symmetry, we only need to prove this if $[[A,B],B]=1$. Let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ and $b_1,b_2 \in B$, it is enough to show that the commutators $[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ commute. Observe that by the Lemma $[a_2,b_2]^{a_1^{-1}} \in [A,B]$:
$$[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]=a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1b_1[a_2,b_2]\underset{b_1 \text { commutes with } [a_2,b_2]}=a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1[a_2,b_2]b_1=a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}[a_2,b_2]^{a_1^{-1}}a_1b_1 =\underset{\text{ using the Lemma and } b_1^{-1} \text{ centralizes }[A,B]}=\\ a_1^{-1}[a_2,b_2]^{a_1^{-1}}b_1^{-1}a_1b_1=[a_2,b_2][a_1,b_1].$$

**Note** (added March 24th 2021) There is still another elegant way to show that $[A,B]$ is abelian, and that is by an appeal to the *Three Subgroups Lemma*:

**Lemma** Let $X,Y,Z$ be subgroups of a group $G$. If $[X,[Y,Z]]=1$ and $[Z,[X,Y]]=1$ then $[Y,[Z,X]]=1$.

Note that the subgroups/letters are shifted cyclically. For a proof and a slight generalization (replacing $1$ by containment in a normal subgroup $N$) see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma). Proofs usually apply the so-called *Hall-Witt Identity*.

Now let's show that if $[A,B]$ is centralized by $B$, $[A,B]$ must be abelian. By the first Lemma, $A$ normalizes $[A,B]$, so $[A,[A,B]] \subseteq [A,B]$, implying $[B,[[A,B],A]]=1$. Further, $[A,[B,[A,B]]]=[A,1]=1$. The Three Subgroups Lemma now yields, $[[A,B],[A,B]]=1$, that is $[A,B]$ is abelian.

Comment: I think my solution is nearly the same to yours......

Comment: The catch is *nearly*. At each step I pointed out why you can interchange certain group elements. But you never used the fact that $[A,B]$ is normalized by $A$.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, each $b \in B$ commutes with $[A, B]$.

$[a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]=(a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1)[a_2,b_2]b_1=(a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1)[a_2,b_2](a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1)^{-1}[a_1,b_1]=[a_2,b_2][a_1,b_1]$

as
$(a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1)[a_2,b_2](a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_1)^{-1}=[a_2,b_2]$ as $b_1$ commutes with any $[a, b]$.

Sorry I don't have any mathtype software please don't be upset.

Comment: @Andrew I edited your answer but I do not think it is correct ...